# 'Randomly' construct symmetric/positive definite pair of matrices with specific generalized eigenvector?

Tags: matlab, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

Given a symmetric matrix `A` and a positive definite matrix `B`, we can find the eigenvalues and generalized eigenvectors with scipy's `scipy.linalg.eigh`, or matlab's `eig`.

Is there a correspondingly-straightforward way to do the reverse?

For example, how can I generate a pair of symmetric/positive definite matrices such that the generalized eigenvector associated with the largest magnitude eigenvalue is a particular vector, `v`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given symmetric A and symmetric, positive definite B, the [generalized
eigenvalue problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Generalized_eigenvalue_problem) is to find nonsingular P and diagonal D such that

```
A P = B P D
```

The diagonal of D holds the generalized eigenvalues, and the columns of P
are the corresponding generalized eigenvectors.

For such a solution, P and B satisfy the B-orthogonality condition

```
P.T B P = I
```

The "reverse" problem can be stated as: given nonsingular P and diagonal D,
find symmetric A and symmetric, positive definite B such that

```
A P = B P D
```

This can be solved with a little algebra.
Multiply on the left by P.T, and use B-orthogonality:

```
P.T A P = D
```

so

```
A = inv(P.T) D inv(P)
```

To get B, solve the B-orthogonality condition

```
B = inv(P.T) inv(P)
  = inv(P P.T)
```

Those are the formulas for A and B given P and D.